# Positioning elements via background - CSS-JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to **position** one of your **HTML element** related to
the  **stretched background** of your page ?

you have made the background stretched ,

now you want to write something exactly next to your logo .

considering the resolutions and browsers

*CSS & JQuery*

If you know any strategy or any good article/ tutorial

I would be glad to hear from you

thanks

Comment: How have you made your background stretched? Please show some code.

Comment: Yes ,
I stretched the image and make it as a full-screen background .
Now I want to put an element next to something we see in the background e.g Logo .
the code isn't available now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the coordinates in the window to match the stretched ones. So if the background image is stretched in the back from the coordinate (0,0) all the way to (window.screen.width, window.screen.height) and image size is lets say (800, 600), and your logo is located on the image's coordinates (44, 100), and you want to know the window's coordinates to match the image's one...

```
function place(div, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h)
{
    //Calculate the window coordinates that match the image coordinates
    var window_x = Math.Floor((window.screen.width/image_w)*image_x);
    var window_y = Math.Floor((window.screen.height/image_h)*image_y);

    //Make divs position absolute
    $("#"+div).css("position", "absolute");

    //Set the left in the window coords that match the images coords
    $("#"+div).css("left", window_x+"px"); 

    //Set the top to match the images coords
    $("#"+div).css("top", window_y+"px");
}
```

You would use the function like this:

```
place("logo_text_div", 44, 100, 800, 600);
```

You can modify the code so it uses Ceil, you would get the coords shifted to the right. Or you could round the window_x and window_y some other way so you get the preccission you want.

Answer (score 0):

`window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` may be helpful to you.